# In drupal9 how to pass field values from page 1 to page2 in webform module?

Tags: forms, webforms

I want previous page values in next page in webform multistep form.
**E.g.** If I've entered a value say **First name: "Tara"**. And then clicked on next button. Then in next page the first name should be retained from page1. Like My name is **Tara** and I work **abc** company.

How can I achieved this using webform module? Or is there any other way to do this. I am using drupal9.

Comment: thanks @cilefen. I will check and try this.

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. Can you please explain? What is [progress] and [#current_page] ?